# App Crash on UIButtonLabel defaultAttributes

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, crash-reports, crashlytics

We have an app crash we are trying to resolve, but I am not sure where to start. The issue appears to be with a call to the defaultAttributes of a UIButtonLabel.

It looks like it is a core call to UIKit rather than coming directly from app code. Any advice on what can be checked here to determine the issue or get closer?

[image]

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x33ab0f66 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x29874a4b -[UIButtonLabel _defaultAttributes] + 154
2  UIKit                          0x297d7a81 -[UILabel font] + 120
3  UIKit                          0x29aed4d3 -[UILabel _contentInsetsFromFonts] + 250
4  UIKit                          0x29c410e3 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentInsets] + 94
5  UIKit                          0x29c411b7 -[_UILabelLayer updateContentLayerSize] + 42
6  QuartzCore                     0x291e7bd1 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 360
7  QuartzCore                     0x291e7a59 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) +   16
8  QuartzCore                     0x291e7447 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 222
9  QuartzCore                     0x291e7251 CA::Transaction::commit() + 324
10 UIKit                          0x297b9699 _afterCACommitHandler + 132
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2630c845 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20
12 CoreFoundation                 0x26309f29 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2630a32b __CFRunLoopRun + 914
14 CoreFoundation                 0x26257db1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
15 CoreFoundation                 0x26257bc3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
16 GraphicsServices               0x2d5e2051 GSEventRunModal + 136
17 UIKit                          0x29822f01 UIApplicationMain + 1440
18 APPNAME                     0x0005120f main (main.m:16)

Comment: Can you post the code around where you are having the issue? Does this error always happen in specific circumstances or is it intermittent? Also a more detailed error message (if one exists) rather than `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and preferably the full symbolicated crash log.

Comment: This is the thread it crashes on in crashalytics, we are not able to reproduce in development environment so cannot find the point of crashing or the code relating to it. It only occurs on ios8 devices. I have edited and pasted the raw thread data too, its the apple thread.

Comment: This kind of crash is almost impossible to find unless you know around which view controller or view the crash occurred. It could very well be an iOS bug but you won't know unless you can reproduce it.

Comment: If you can't debug / get a crash in the development environment (even with a release profile) then I'm not sure how you can start. You need to know where the problem is occurring in order to track down if it's you or Apple causing the problem. Perhaps a friendly beta-tester can install a special version with extremely heavy logging?

Comment: Thanks both, this is one of those errors that occur really irregularly for small amount of users. I just wondered if I was being stupid and there was anyway to tell what the issue was. Even with a beta tester having a large logging app I doubt they would be able to reproduce. Just looking at the crash info it looks like it could well be an Apple/iOS8 issue but I cannot be sure. Maybe we will just have to continue to test and test until we can reproduce something in a test environment?

Comment: FWIW, I have a crash with the same call stack in one of my apps, on iOS8-only.  Haven't figured it out.

Comment: Have you figured out the issue? I am also getting issues reported with almost same stack race. Please let me know if you got any clue on this.

Comment: @QUserS - never able to reproduce on a testing device or sim, for iOS8. As users faded out and upgraded we have seen it a lot less... We was never able to track it down, but if you have any luck be sure to come back and post an answer! good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar crash, which was due to a message sent to a deallocated instance. I found that out by enabling zombies.

Comment: Was the deallocated instance a viewcontroller or just the button itself?